# Accessing SimpleXML Object attribute

Tags: php, object, simplexml

Have this print output from `print_r($theobject);`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [label] => a
        )

    [0] => Abnormal psychology : Abnormal psychology :
)
```

Just cannot find a way to get  element 0 which is "Abnormal psychology :"

Lets call the object as `$theobject`
I did `$theobject[0]`, didn't get anything.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just cast the object to a string:

```
$str = (string)$theobject;
```